# Connecting 2 Pi in ssh using keys instead of password

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have 2 Pi on 2 separate networks, running raspbian, one is a web server, the other is used to backup (let's say pi-server and pi-backup), and I would like pi-server to ssh to pi-backup in order to backup data. I manage to do that typing this on pi-server :

```
ssh -p 4444 userBackup@pibackup.fr
userBackup@pibackup.fr's password :
```

I type my password and then I  am prompted on pi-backup and all is great (pi-backup's ssh listen on 22 but I redirect 4444 to 22 with my router, heard it was more secured)

As I would like to script the connexion to be able to cron it everyday, I can't authentify by password, so I tried keys : I generated a key on pi-server using

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then I copy/pasted id_rsa_pub in /home/userBackup/.ssh/authorized_keys... But I am still asked for a password when I try to connect.

What I find surprising, is that I already connect to pi-backup with a key (of course different) from my main PC, which is on the same local network than pi-backup. So I have two lines in authorized_keys.

Do you have any idea what could be going wrong ? Not being on the same local network shouldn't be a problem, should it ?

[edit] When I try

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 4444 userBackup@pibackup.fr
```

here is what I get :

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pibackup.fr [90.10.1.1] port 4444.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/userServer/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/userServer/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 6b:5f:aa:aa:aa0c:aa:33:97:aa:56:aa:39:00:6f:79
debug1: Host '[pibackup.fr]:4444' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/userBackup/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '[90.10.1.1]:4444' to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/userServer/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
userBackup@piBackup.fr's password:
```

I have noted that in the last lines, he says "Offering RSA public key: /home/userServer/.ssh/id_rsa" so I tried with my public key instead, but nothing changed.

Comment: You should call `ssh-add` to add you key on pi-seserver then you could use `ssh` without password.

Comment: when I try that I get "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." no matter if I try with or without sudo

Comment: Oh ok! Then you must do it before: `eval \`ssh-agent\``. In your cron file you don't need (I think) to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem : on serverBackup, userBackup wasn't the owner of authorized_keys... that's all ;). I still don't understand why it was working when I connected from my lan PC, but now all is great ! Ankirama, thansk for your time and advices.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify your key generated with `ssh-keygen` in your `ssh` line. You can do it like this:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/blah.key -p 4444 userBackup@pibackup.fr` it will load your key.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have no file blah.key. ssh-keygen only generated a id_rsa.pub and a id_rsa file. Should I use one of those ? besides, why adding id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys wasn't enough ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use `id_rsa`. blah.key was an example sorry.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it didn't worked, I'm still asked for a password (when I give it, it works)

Comment: Did you add a passphrase when you generated your key? Can you try to connect via `ssh` with `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 4444 userBackup@pibackup.fr` ? `-v` enable the verbose mode. Then copy the result please.

Comment: I did not entered a passphrase, I have just copied the result of the command you asked in the main part of the question (not enough room here)